# Setting up a kickstart boot-dvd

Tags: redhat, kickstart

I'm not sure if this is the right stackexchange site to ask this on. But I'm trying to set up a kickstart boot dvd for RHEL5.5. I also want to add some RPM's on it to install after with the %post script section. My question is, how can I add these rpm's as well as my .ks file to the DVD ISO? Is there a program I need to open the ISO, extract all the data, then remake it into an ISO for burning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the hardest part of setting up a custom boot CD is getting the bootloader to function correctly from the CD after remaster.

To remaster the CD it is necessary to update some metadata for the isolinux setup. I think it is covered on either page 3 or 4 of Frank's link.

```
mkisofs -iso-level 4 -l -R -J -joliet-long -D -V "UBCD501" -o "../custom.iso" -b
  "isolinux/isolinux.bin" -c "isolinux/boot.catalog"  \
   -hide "isolinux/boot.catalog" -hide-joliet "isolinux/boot.catalog" 
   -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table .
```

Execute this from the top level folder containing the extracted contents of your CD.

On a related note I personally like to keep a dedicated local repository for my servers. It makes the updates process easier and it also provides a *really* convenient way to keep a set of kickstart files. I put a http reference for my kickstart file and load it off the server along with the latest versions of whatever packages I want to install. It is way faster than trying to run the updates after the fact.

NOTE - this works flawlessly for remastering RHEL / CentOS boxes. Haven't tested elsewhere.

Comment: Where did the link go? :(

Comment: Agreed--I'm having my own issues with this, and the link would be helpful.